Compositor Volumetrics
So I've got an area light and I'm using volumetric scatter shader on a box covering the entire scene. When I do that I get the result shown below. I made the scatter density quite high to show the point.
Here's the problem: I'd prefer to do the scatter/volumetrics in my composition setup rather than at render time. I have "mist" enabled but I don't think that's going to be useful. Seems to be more about fog than scene lighting.
Is it possible to do volume lighting in the compositor?


Mist is dependent on the distance from the camera, it is kind of like a clipped z-depth. It is not part of the scene so it cannot interact with scene lights. Everything done in the Compositor is post processing. So to do anything on any passes etc. they have to be rendered beforehand to get the information what these passes contain.

So there's no "scatter pass" as such.  I would have to construct that myself in a first pass.  I was hoping there's some kind of "local density" surface for scatter knocking around but I suppose it's more complicated than that.
